# Use foreach inside an Angular Concatmap

Tags: angular, rxjs

Problem. I am required to post make 3 HTTP post requests to 3 different endpoints. I am using concatMap to sequentially HTTP post to an observable. My issue takes place when I need to use a foreach loop to get each value from the formarray.

My code is returning an error.

```
core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
    at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:69)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:57)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:34)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:46)
    at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

What I have tried…

```
concatMap(() => this.incentiveRecurringEntryForm.controls['entryRowsRecurring'].value.forEach(r => {
        this.updateRecurringWithJobID = addToObject(r, 'IncentiveID', this.job_id);
        console.log(this.updateRecurringWithJobID)
        return this.routeService.postIncentive_Add_Recurring(this.updateRecurringWithJobID).subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res)
          }
        )
      })),
```

Comment: Have you tried using map? forEach does not return anything

Comment: @OscarLudick I haven't tried map. It's strange because the forEach works when I use it outside of the concatMap. It just throws this error when I use it inside of the concatMap.

Comment: yeah, concatMap expects an observable, promise or array, your code is equivalent to this `concatMap(() => return undefined);` you must return something like a new Observable.

Comment: It's because concatMap expects an argument but `forEach` is actually returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`concatMap` is an operator. It needs a source observable. I've called it `someObservable` in my example.

`concatMap` expects an observable, not an array of observables. You can use `concat` on a list of observables however. `Concat` create an observable for you and doesn't need a source observable *(you'll notice it's not 'in a pipe')*

`concat` requires a list of observables, but `forEach` returns `undefined`. I use map instead. Array's `map` returns an array of the same structure as the input array with the given transformation described by the supplied lambda.

You need a list of `observable`s, so trying to subscribe doesn't work as that will return a list of `subscription`s. Just let the `concat` do the subscribing.

Here's what the would look like:

```ts
someObservable.pipe(

  /* More operators? ,*/
  
  concatMap(() => concat(...
    this.incentiveRecurringEntryForm.controls['entryRowsRecurring'].value.map(r => {
      this.updateRecurringWithJobID = addToObject(r, 'IncentiveID', this.job_id);
      console.log(this.updateRecurringWithJobID);
      return this.routeService.postIncentive_Add_Recurring(this.updateRecurringWithJobID);
    })
  )),

  /* More operators? */

).subscribe(console.log);
```